# Drupal theme version and drupal engine version compatibility

Tags: theming

I purchased a theme some time ago that specifies 
Drupal Compatibility:   7.x
Drupal Engine:  7.22

I am unclear how the Compatibility and engine versions correlate ...beginner :)

I would like to deploy this theme to a website and the host provides Drupal Engine 7.39.  Should the theme work for this version of the drupal engine?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) It's not possible to say without seeing the code - ask the people you purchased it from if the compatibility is "at least" or "only" for "Drupal Engine: 7.22". If the response is "only", run a mile - there have been major security holes found in core in the meantime, and if you use 7.22 it's very likely your site/server will be compromised. FYI the current stable, secure version is 7.43 - installing 7.39 is potentially a very bad idea